# Browse file and store file url for uploading it later

Tags: scala, file-upload, lift

I have a form in which you enter some data and you are able to attach files. All I wanna do is have a Browse button so i can select the file and store that file url in some var, so later when i want to submit the form...y can read that var and upload the file using its url. Im using Scala Lift. I search for examples in the web but couldnt find anything helpful. I only want to select the file and store the file url. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't store path to file on client's drive. Even if you get path like this, you can't upload file that is not manually selected by client.

I suggest doing AJAX based client.